# ARC conversion of TPMultiLayoutViewController; Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'const void *' is disallowed with ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to use [TPMultiLayoutViewController](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPMultiLayoutViewController) in a project using ARC, but am bumping into the following error:-

> Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'const void *' is disallowed with ARC

I'm really not sure how to tackle this; does it need explicitly converting? and how would I do that?

```
- (void)addAttributesForSubviewHierarchy:(UIView*)view associatedWithSubviewHierarchy:(UIView*)associatedView toTable:(NSMutableDictionary*)table {
    [table setObject:[self attributesForView:view] forKey:[NSValue valueWithPointer:associatedView]];

    if ( ![self shouldDescendIntoSubviewsOfView:view] ) return;

    for ( UIView *subview in view.subviews ) {
        UIView *associatedSubView = (view == associatedView ? subview : [self findAssociatedViewForView:subview amongViews:associatedView.subviews]);
        if ( associatedSubView ) {
            [self addAttributesForSubviewHierarchy:subview associatedWithSubviewHierarchy:associatedSubView toTable:table];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the first one in the method 
`[table setObject:[self attributesForView:view] forKey:[NSValue valueWithPointer:associatedView]];`

Comment: its this part in particular `[NSValue valueWithPointer:associatedView]`

Comment: Why not put the associatedView directly into the NSDictionary?

Comment: In general `(__bridge void *)` however I don't understand why you would get that error there. `setObject:forKey` should take `id`

Comment: Can you use a view object as a key?

Comment: No; keys need to conform to the `NSCopying` protocol.

Comment: Well that seems to have worked (__bridge void *)!

Comment: Is there a good resource on what __bridge does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting the error because of this:

```
[NSValue valueWithPointer:associatedView]
```

Since `valueWithPointer:` takes a `const char *`. You can work around this by doing what @ user1139069 suggested:

```
[NSValue valueWithPointer:(__bridge void *)associatedView]
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you use `[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:]` instead of `[NSValue valueWithPointer:]`?